# ghost blog client id secret showing in head

Tags: ghost-blog

I am developing ghost blog for production site using API beta and using view source I can see as below:

```
ghost.init({
    clientId: "ghost-frontend",
    clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
});
```

in the html head section, is this right? Isn't secret supposed to be hidden? Although obviously being client meaning it is supposed to be in the client-side.

Comment: I think you need to take it into server end and its secure too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ghost Documentation, these credentials are used for Client Authentication. Client Authentication only gives access to the public Ghost API, which is basically anything your readers can currently access on your ghost blog without authentication. So making these credentials public should not be a problem since they can only be used to access public information. Also, the API request must currently come from the same domain as the one specified in your config.js file.

From the [Ghost API Documentation](http://api.ghost.org/docs/getting-started):

> Please be aware that as of current Ghost versions, Client Authentication is only available as part of the Public API Beta, and only provides access to read public data.
>
> The 'Public' API essentially reflects the behaviour of a blog - it provides 
>   read access to any data that a user/reader of a blog would be able to see.
>
> For the time being Client Authentication is restricted to the domain specified in your config.js file, meaning that requests that come from a theme will work, but requests from another site will not.

And here is why they're doing this:

> Ghost’s JSON API has the same abilities as the admin panel (in fact the admin panel uses the API) – so it will eventually be possible to read and write any data you have permissions for using the API. Some data in a blog is inherently public: your published posts, tags, and active users (minus their email and password hash). For this first release, we’re only providing access to read public data.
>
> Additionally, for the first release, we’re only making it possible to read that data from within the theme / frontend of your blog. This is because the ‘client’ authentication that we’re providing only permits requests from internally known domains. All of this will be expanded upon in later releases where there will be a UI to create clients for different kinds of access.

See https://help.ghost.org/article/11-public-api-beta